# Python setup tools normalizes version name based on common naming convention

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

Error

```
/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:476: UserWarning: Normalizing '2.1.0c1' to '2.1.0rc1'
  normalized_version,
[Pipeline] sh
+ python3 -m twine upload --config-file .pypirc -r nesus dist/forecasting_model-2.1.0c1.tar.gz
InvalidDistribution: Cannot find file (or expand pattern): 'dist/forecasting_model-2.1.0c1.tar.gz'
```

My code for naming convention

```
 model_version_trunc = re.split("a|b|c", current_version)[0] if len(re.split("a|b|c", current_version)) > 0 else current_version
    sub_version = int(re.split("a|b|c", current_version)[1]) if len(re.split("a|b|c", current_version)) > 1 else 1
    VERSION = current_version

    if BRANCH == 'workbench':
        letter = 'a'
    elif BRANCH == 'development':
        letter = 'b'
    elif BRANCH == 'master':
        sub_version = ''
        letter = ''
    else:
        letter = 'c'

    VERSION = f'{model_version_trunc}{letter}{sub_version}'

    # Check Version
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(MODEL_LIBRARY)
    versions_so_far = r.html.links
    version_already_exists = list(set([f'{VERSION}/']).intersection(versions_so_far))
    logger.info(f'Updated Version: {VERSION}')
    logger.info(f'Version Exists: {version_already_exists}')

    if len(version_already_exists) > 0:
        for x in version_already_exists:
            ''' 
                Fallback if versions are similar:

                If a version is an alpha/beta/branch release, update the release number
                If a version is just the standard version then udpate the minor version.
            '''
```

I checked the link here -

https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#choosing-a-versioning-scheme

for the popular naming convention.

Is there a way to fix this sort of sentience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version scheme is not compatible with [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440). The link you mentioned in the question explicitly states:

> Different Python projects may use different versioning schemes based on the needs of that particular project, but **all of them are required to comply with the flexible public version scheme specified in PEP 440** in order to be supported in tools and libraries like `pip` and `setuptools`.

PEP 440 allows only five suffixes: `a`, `b`, `rc`, `post` and `dev`.

Also note that `a` and `b` suffixes identify alpha and beta releases, so check whether your versioning scheme reflects that (does the `workbench` branch really contain the alpha release?).

If you need to store additional information in the version, you can use the [local version identifier](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#local-version-identifiers) to separate the version part. Examples:

```
1.2.3+spam
1.0.0.dev999+eggs123.bacon456
```

However, restating PEP 440 once again:

> Local version identifiers SHOULD NOT be used when publishing upstream projects to a public index server, but MAY be used to identify private builds created directly from the project source. [...] As the Python Package Index is intended solely for indexing and hosting upstream projects, it MUST NOT allow the use of local version identifiers.